# Preview Blob Image to HTML5 <img>

Tags: java, html

Im developing a website using **Java**, I have an **image** stored in the database as **BLOB**, when it is loaded in the browser, the output looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,[-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,...too long....
    </div>
</div>
```

It is a **BROKEN IMAGE**, when I preview it in the browser.

My code looks something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${mybyte}/>
```

Here's the console error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

**How to fix this one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your `byte[]` to Base64 string, see [java.util.Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(byte[] src)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) method, and display that string instead of `mybyte` array.